# Highcharts,js Column Chart Won't show negative values

Tags: highcharts

Hi I am trying to make my column chart display negative values. I have looked through many examples and can't find a solution.

My code is shown below:

```
/***************************************************************
 * container: chart_1_2
 ***************************************************************/
var chart_1_2_Options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_1_2',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            pointWidth: 30,
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
};

/**
 * initialize the chart
 */
var chart_1_2 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_1_2_Options);
chart_1_2.showLoading();

/**
 * callback to be called from the bundled ajax calls
 */
function onChart_1_2_DataReceived(data) {
    console.log(data);
    /**
     * do something with the data
     */
    var seriesoptions = [
        {
            type: 'column',
            lineWidth: 2,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineWidth: 2
                }
            },
            color: '#e25826',
            name: 'Sales'
        }
    ];

    chart_1_2_Options.series = seriesoptions;
    var chart_1_2 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_1_2_Options);
    chart_1_2.series[0].setData(data);
}

/***************************************************************
 * end of chart_2_1
 **************************************************************/
```

The array which is passed into the `onChart_1_2_DataReceived()` function is as follows:

[image: array]

As you can see the array contains positive and negative values, all of the positive values are displayed on the chart but all the negative values are displayed as 0's.

[image: chart]

I am using highcharts version 5.0.7. I have tried setting the yAxis min to -50 and that doesn't make any difference either.

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfyn4jk7/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Could you explain how this examples helps? The example looks no different to my code but mine doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working for you. Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Perhaps other options are wrong.

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem. Here is a working chart with your settings and the first 3 elem of data: https://jsfiddle.net/wz782u4t/